# How do I tell Safari not to change the active tab on the error console when I reload a page?

Tags: safari

When I reload a page on Safari 9.0, El Capitain, with the developer tools open and the "Console" tab active, it will automatically switch to the "Resources" tab. How do I stop this deliberately stupid behavior?

Comment: I was about to duplicate this question with even a screen recording to demonstrate this issue: http://gfycat.com/InsignificantSpiritedGrackle, before I found yours. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @adita menon no problem! It works fine if the app isn't split screen.

Comment: This is always happening with me on Safari 10.1.2 since I installed extensions like JSONView, AdBlock...

Answer (score 3):

Close the Resources tab then it always stays on the tab where you are on every reload

Answer (score 2):

Usually I open the developer tools by using the "Inspect Element" context menu, and get the same behaviour as you describe (automatically switching to the Resource tab).

So I experimented and found an answer: If you open the developer tools to the Console tab by selecting Develop > Show Error Console from the menu, it will stay on the Console tab after a page refresh.

Also, if you open the developer tools using the "Toggle Web Inspector" icon or the Develop > Show Web Inspector menu item, it will stay on whatever tab you have selected after a page refresh.

Comment: Which you can also enable by ⌘⌥C (the "Elements" tab by ⌘⌥I)

Comment: Okay, so the above worked for me every time when I tested it before answering the question (10+ times). However, today it was automatically switching to the Resources tab (and sometimes the Storage tab) no matter what I did. So you can probably disregard my answer.