# "Force Sticky Console": Safari devtools shifts away from Console to DOM inspector on reload

Tags: safari, macos, development, console

When I'm working with the DevTools open, if I refresh the page, DevTools automatically switches to the DOM Inspector tab instead of staying on the console. Here's an animated GIF image to demonstrate the behaviour: http://gfycat.com/InsignificantSpiritedGrackle

How do I make sure DevTools always stays on the Console even after refresh?

There was an answer proposed here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218126/43068 but it's not a 100% solution (as commented by the author on that answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible, if you keep the developer tools docked in the window. If you undock the developer tools, the tools respect that they have been opened using Show Error Console.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Comment: Thanks, to me it seems very on/off when docked - sometimes it acts sanely other times it doesn't. But when undocked as of now it seems to behave like you say.

Comment: It definitely does seem like a bug. It's an interesting question—I've reached my vote limit today but I will +1 the question tomorrow.